Is it possible to connect external monitor to dedicated graphics card on laptop if no port is available?
I have msi sword 15 a12 laptop. It doesnt have any port connected to dedicated gfx which is 3050ti. Is there any way to connect external monitor and make it use the dedicated graphics card?


Yes; Uninstall the Intel drivers and install the Nvidia drivers once you do that your system will only use the dGPU.

@JayCravens It does have an hdmi port but it seems it uses only intel graphics when connected to external display.

@Ramhound I understand that the laptop will use the discrete gpu but I want my external monitor which is connected to my laptop to also use the discrete gpu through the hdmi port.

Ah, well, if it's not a dual-display device, the there's only one video out on the board.  So having it display both, simultaneously, would need dual display.  You can purchase a usb device and make it dual display.  Link

@VickySoni - Which is the purpose of my suggestion.

@Ramhound It doesn't seem to work. Laptop wont use nvidia gpu and show microsoft display in settings.

You installed the Nvidia drivers? Windows only normally detects the Microsoft Display when no display drivers are installed.

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/physx-not-showing-connection-between-gpu-and-my-screen/287080
